# Authenticating Password after Login - JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss

This may be a silly question, but I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere.

I currently have the JBOSS system (EAP 6.3.3) set up to login properly using the Java EE 6 method `HttpServletRequest#login(username, password)`. However, I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how I can authenticate the username and password *after* logging in without destroying the session.

I'm planning on using this in the event a user wants to change settings or if a session times out so I can implement a lock screen while still saving the application's state. Is this possible?

Comment: I am trying to understand your question. but i am thinking what is the question here. Can you post your code so i can understand your question properly.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how to clarify further. I don't have any code because I have no idea how to implement it.

Basically, after I've logged in with `login`, I'm trying to authenticate the password again without using that same method, but still using the credentials in the JBOSS container.

Comment: As per my understand Login means you going to authenticate with userid and password. Why you want to authenticate again?

Comment: As I said in the question, I want to prompt for password when the user changes settings or, if the session hits a certain timeout, prompting for their password after the screen has locked.